# java web crawler cannot recognize non English characters

Tags: java, character, web-crawler, utf, non-english

I crawled list of movies and stored them in my database. Everything works fine for movies which contain only English characters but the problem is that some of movie names that contain non English characters cannot be displayed correctly. For example, the Italian movie "Il più crudele dei giorni" is stored as "Il pi& ugrave;  crudele dei giorni".

Could someone kindly let me know if there is any solution? (I know that I can set the language for the crawler, I already crawled movie titles in Italian as well, but when I want to crawl English titles, there are still some movies in Imdb which has non English characters)

**EDIT:** Here is my code:

```
String baseUrl = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&count=250&sort=num_votes,desc&start="+start+"&title_type=feature&view=simple";

label1:  try {

     org.jsoup.Connection con = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21").header("Accept-Language", "en");
     con.timeout(30000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true);
     Response resp = con.execute();
     Document doc = null;

     if (resp.statusCode() == 200) {

         doc = con.get();                                       

         Elements myElements = doc.getElementsByClass("results").first().getElementsByTag("table");
         Elements trs = myElements.select(":not(thead) tr");

         for (int i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {

             Element tr = trs.get(i);
             Elements tds = tr.select("td");

             for (int j = 3; j < tds.size(); j++) {

                 Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
                 String titleId = links.attr("href");
                 String movietitle = links.html();    

                  //I ADDED YOUR CODE HERE
                   Charset c = Charset.forName("UTF-16BE");

                        ByteBuffer b = c.encode(movietitle);
                        for (int m = 0; b.hasRemaining(); m++) {
                            int charValue = (b.get()) & 0xff;
                            System.out.print((char) charValue);
                        }   

               // try{    

                //   String query = "INSERT into test (movieName,ImdbId)" + "VALUES (?,?)";
    //               PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    //               preparedStmt.setString (1, movietitle);
      //               preparedStmt.setString (2, titleId );
       //          }catch (Exception e)
        //       {
        //           e.printStackTrace();
        //       }
```

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Tirath: Thanks for the useful article. Actually, I got the Movietitle and store in DB. Should I add the encoding lines after I store the movie name in String "movietitle"?. Could you please see my update in order to see the original code?

Comment: @Tirath: even by adding those encoding lines, Still i get the same output :( Could u plz help me I am really confused

Comment: Have not worked with `IO`. Can you try using `PrintStream` class. Use `PrintStream(OutputStream out,boolean autoFlush,String encoding)` constructor and write to the console. If this does not work than try writing to a file instead.

Comment: Code is fine. Its the console to which you are printing is causing the problem. I just tried it in eclipse and it printed boxes for the accented characters. So, better try writing to a file and then see the output.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I copy pasted the string shared in the question and tried

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String...a) throws Exception {
        String s = "Il più crudele dei giorni";
        Charset c = Charset.forName("UTF-16BE");

        ByteBuffer b = c.encode(s);
        for (int i = 0; b.hasRemaining(); i++) {
            int charValue = (b.get()) & 0xff;
            System.out.print((char) charValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the `s` as it is on the console. I assume that you already have part of code which writes to a file. You can try integrating the above code if it works for you.

Comment: thank for your help, Is there anyway not to crawl from the beginning? (Since there are 100,000 movies .. I mean is there any way to change and update them in database?

Comment: All I can think of is - write a separate class which will read the `column values` from the `table` in question and update it back in the DB.

Comment: I tried your code, but it did not work for me .. nothing happened :(

Comment: nothing? not printing as it is - is understandable.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand... I thought it should return Il più crudele dei giorni... could you explain e bit more?:|